# Google Map doesnt' display markers after getting external JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i could read lat, lgt etc from an external JSON in my website. But i cannot figure why markers (markerclusterer) are not displayd.

I could show you two example:

1 => http://www.webtemplum.com/geo/   perfectly functioning

2 => http://www.webtemplum.com/geo/test.php    it doesn't functioning.

You could note for link 2 in console that i can read correctly JSON. Maybe I need to move some piece of code in other parts (difference on loading?)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my lat / lgt was in E6.

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(    (data[i].lat/1E6),
                                                            (data[i].lng/1E6)   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give different id's for the div's that you are assigning maps

```
<div id="mappa1" class="shadow610" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
```

and

```
<div id="mapp2" class="shadow610" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Dont forgot to re assign the map function to the new div id also

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that this is the issue. Pages are different so they don't conflict...

Comment: Ofcourse but if you give different ids then it may not lead any conflicts and also the pages are different the map page that occuring to your site will conflict as much as possible